# Creating an observable from multiple observable values

Tags: angular, rxjs

In one of my components I need to loop over an array of ids and make an API call for each one. The api calls return observables and at the moment I am just subscribing to each one in the loop and adding its value to an array. I don't believe this is good because I am subscribing to each call individually. Is there a way I can use something like `mergeMap` or similar to create an observable of all the combined values from the loop?

That way I have one observable that I can subscribe to (or use the async pipe in the HTML) instead of many?

Here is my controller code:

```
export class GraphTablesComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() meta: any;
  @Input() entityId: number;
  kpiData: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getKpiData();
  }

  private getKpiData(): void {
    for (const m of this.meta) {
      this.apiService.post(`${Endpoints.KPIS}execute/${m._bid}/${this.entityId}`, {}).subscribe(d => this.kpiData.push(d));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ForkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to achieve it

```
private getKpiData(): void {
    let requestArray = [];

    for (const m of this.meta) {
      requestArray.push(this.apiService.post(`${Endpoints.KPIS}execute/${m._bid}/${this.entityId}`, {}))
    }

    forkJoin(requestArray).subscribe(data => {
      this.response1 = data[0];
      this.response2 = data[1];
    });
}
```

If you directly want to add it in template,

.ts

```
this.data$ =  forkJoin(requestArray)
```

.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async; let data">
   {{data | json}}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Could I just do `this.data = forkJoin(requestArray);` and then just subscribe to that in the HTML?

Comment: No, you have to subscribe. Forkjoin returns observable. `forkJoin(requestArray).subscribe(data => { Could I just do this.data = data ...`

Comment: You can just do this.data | async providing that data is transformed into your desire format

Comment: Yes, that is another way of handing observables. But

Comment: Just let me add, that it would be better to use the map function `const requestArray = this.meta.map(m => this.apiService.post(`${Endpoints.KPIS}execute/${m._bid}/${this.entityId}`, {}))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat`. It bundles all observables and makes them one after another (which means it retains also the order):

Because I use it myself, I can give you a simple example to it:

Service method:

```
  /**
   * Makes a chain of requests one by one
   * type
   * @param {any[]} data
   * @return {Observable<any>}
   */
  generateTexts(data: any[]): Observable<any> {

    return concat(
      ...data.map(entry => this.httpClient.post(this.url, this.getRequestBody(entry))
    );
  }
```

Observable which receives the values:

```
this.apiService.generateTexts(data).subscribe((response) => {
  // Handle response, this will be called multiple times as long as
  // requests are made
  // 'reponse' contains 1 request response
});
```

Comment: forkJoin also retains order in it's final response FYI. the main diffs are that concat executes sequentially and forkJoin is parralel, and concat will emit multiple times while forkJoin emits once with all values.

Comment: Yes it depends on the use case. In my case the server performance doesn't allow to do things simultaneously